# interpolate numerical variables in a data.table with factor variables

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, interpolation, locf

I am attempting to interpolate multiple numeric columns of a data.table `dt`. It can be filled with NA or with something like `na_locf`. In my real data might be more than one factor column. Here is my example data:

```
dt <- structure(list(time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), 
                     a = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, NA, 1L, 
                                               2L, NA), .Label = c("0", "1", "3"), class = "factor"), b = c(1.28, 
                                                                                                                   1.27, NA, 1.25, NA, 1.25, NA, 1.23, NA, 1.21), c = c(104.45, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      NA, 104.45, NA, 104.3, NA, 104.45, NA, 104.38, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

    time    a    b      c
 1:  0.0    0 1.28 104.45
 2:  0.0 <NA> 1.27     NA
 3:  0.0 <NA>   NA 104.45
 4:  0.0    0 1.25     NA
 5:  0.0    3   NA 104.30
 6:  0.0    1 1.25     NA
 7:  0.1 <NA>   NA 104.45
 8:  0.1    0 1.23     NA
 9:  0.1    1   NA 104.38
10:  0.1 <NA> 1.21     NA
```

and the result should look like this:

```
dtres <- structure(list(time = c(0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 
                                 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1), a = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
                                                                                                                                            "1", "3"), class = "factor"), b = c(1.2625, 1.2625, 1.2625, 1.25825, 
                                                                                                                                                                                1.254, 1.24975, 1.2455, 1.24125, 1.237, 1.23275, 1.2285, 1.22425, 
                                                                                                                                                                                1.22, 1.22), c = c(104.4, 104.4, 104.4, 104.4015, 104.403, 104.4045, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   104.406, 104.4075, 104.409, 104.4105, 104.412, 104.4135, 104.415, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   104.415)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

    time a       b        c
 1: 0.00 0 1.26250 104.4000
 2: 0.00 3 1.26250 104.4000
 3: 0.00 1 1.26250 104.4000
 4: 0.01 1 1.25825 104.4015
 5: 0.02 1 1.25400 104.4030
 6: 0.03 1 1.24975 104.4045
 7: 0.04 1 1.24550 104.4060
 8: 0.05 1 1.24125 104.4075
 9: 0.06 1 1.23700 104.4090
10: 0.07 1 1.23275 104.4105
11: 0.08 1 1.22850 104.4120
12: 0.09 1 1.22425 104.4135
13: 0.10 0 1.22000 104.4150
14: 0.10 1 1.22000 104.4150
```

For the interpolation I am using this function:

```
library(zoo)
interpTime <- seq(0, 0.1, by = 0.01)
interp_dt <- function(ecuData) {
  ecuData <- ecuData[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if (is.numeric(x)) na.approx(x, time, xout = interpTime, method = "linear", ties = mean))]
  return(ecuData)
}
```

But I am not able to do the interpolation with the numeric columns AND treat the factor columns the desired way. The factor column `a` should be filled with NA or `na_locf`, I am not sure about that. If there are multiple factor values for one point in time, they should also be there, so there are for example like multiple rows for one point in time (in my example `time = 0`)
Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: @akrun yes, because I don`t know how to treat the factor columns in any way

Comment: @akrun, yes i think so, but if the values are not filled and instead NA it should also be fine

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could look like this:

1. First treat all the columns that are numeric with locf
2. Then apply your desired procedure for factor columns

I am using **imputeTS** now for this example, because this automatically applies locf to all numeric columns and leaves the factor columns unchanged.
If you want to also apply `na_locf` to factor variables, you can use **zoo**, since this package as far as I know also does locf for non-numeric inputs.

```
library(imputeTS)
na_locf(dt)
```

That would be all the required code, for applying locf to all numeric columns of `dt`. Afterwards you can perform your actions on the factor columns.